# Adding Export Import functions to a already compiled dll

Tags: c++, dll, export

I am new here  . I want to add some function to import export table of dll /exe without replacing any one which already exist .
Can you please help me ?
I am still a novice pogramer so please teach me step by step .
Thank you
ALso any app exist for doing such task.
Please help me
Thank you